# storing a list af strings that have sub lists in a json file in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am working with python and I have data like this :

```
RedHat Enterprise Linux ES 2.1 IA64
RedHat Enterprise Linux ES 2.1
Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS 2.1
Linux kernel 2.6.9 
Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc3
Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc1
    + Ubuntu Ubuntu Linux 4.1 ppc
    + Ubuntu Ubuntu Linux 4.1 ia64
Linux kernel 2.6.8
```

I want to store this information in a json file.but I don't know how!
It's like that I have a list of RedHats and Linuxes and Ubuntus are sublist of Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc1 in my list like this list:

```
{"RedHat Enterprise Linux ES 2.1 IA64":{} ,"RedHat Enterprise Linux ES 2.1":{} ,"Red Hat Enterprise":{"Linux AS 2.1","Linux kernel 2.6.9","Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc3","Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc1"},"Linux kernel 2.6.8":{}}
```

this is my whole string:

```
'RedHat Enterprise Linux WS  2.1 IA64RedHat Enterprise Linux WS  2.1RedHat Enterprise Linux ES  2.1 IA64RedHat Enterprise Linux ES  2.1Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS  2.1 IA64Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS  2.1Linux kernel 2.6.9 Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc3Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc2Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc1+ Ubuntu Ubuntu Linux 4.1 ppc+ Ubuntu Ubuntu Linux 4.1 ia64+ Ubuntu Ubuntu Linux 4.1 ia32Linux kernel 2.6.8 Linux kernel 2.6.7 rc1Linux kernel 2.6.7 Linux kernel 2.6.6 rc1Linux kernel 2.6.6 Linux kernel 2.6.5 Linux kernel 2.6.4 Linux kernel 2.6.3 Linux kernel 2.6.2 Linux kernel 2.6.1 -rc2Linux kernel 2.6.1 -rc1Linux kernel 2.6.1 Linux kernel 2.6 .10Linux kernel 2.6 -test9-CVSLinux kernel 2.6 -test9Linux kernel 2.6 -test8Linux kernel 2.6 -test7Linux kernel 2.6 -test6Linux kernel 2.6 -test5Linux kernel 2.6 -test4Linux kernel 2.6 -test3Linux kernel 2.6 -test2Linux kernel 2.6 -test11Linux kernel 2.6 -test10Linux kernel 2.6 -test1Linux kernel 2.6 Linux kernel 2.4.28 + Trustix Secure Enterprise Linux 2.0 + Trustix Secure Linux 2.2 + Trustix Secure Linux 2.1 + Trustix Secure Linux 2.0 Linux kernel 2.4.27 -pre5Linux kernel 2.4.27 -pre4Linux kernel 2.4.27 -pre3Linux kernel 2.4.27 -pre2Linux kernel 2.4.27 -pre1Linux kernel 2.4.27 Linux kernel 2.4.26 Linux kernel 2.4.25 Linux kernel 2.4.24 -ow1Linux kernel 2.4.24 Linux kernel 2.4.23 -pre9Linux kernel 2.4.23 -ow2Linux kernel 2.4.23 + Trustix Secure Linux 2.0 Linux kernel 2.4.22 + Devil-Linux Devil-Linux 1.0.5 + Devil-Linux Devil-Linux 1.0.4 + Mandriva Linux Mandrake 9.2  amd64+ Mandriva Linux Mandrake 9.2 + Red Hat Fedora  Core1+ Slackware Linux 9.1 Linux kernel 2.4.21 pre7Linux kernel 2.4.21 pre4Linux kernel 2.4.21 pre1Linux kernel 2.4.21 + Conectiva Linux 9.0 + Mandriva Linux Mandrake 9.1 ppc+ Mandriva Linux Mandrake 9.1 + Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS  3+ RedHat Desktop 3.0 + RedHat Enterprise Linux ES  3+ RedHat Enterprise Linux WS  3+ S.u.S.E. Linux Personal 9.0 x86_64+ S.u.S.E. Linux Personal 9.0 + SuSE SUSE Linux Enterprise Server  8Linux kernel 2.4.20 Linux kernel 2.4.19 -pre6Linux kernel 2.4.19 -pre5Linux kernel 2.4.19 -pre4Linux kernel 2.4.19 -pre3Linux kernel 2.4.19 -pre2Linux kernel 2.4.19 -pre1Linux kernel 2.4.19 + Conectiva Linux 8.0 + Conectiva Linux Enterprise Edition 1.0 + MandrakeSoft Corporate Server 2.1  x86_64+ MandrakeSoft Corporate Server 2.1 + MandrakeSoft Multi Network Firewall 2.0 + Mandriva Linux Mandrake 9.0 + S.u.S.E. Linux 8.1 + Slackware Linux  -current+ SuSE SUSE Linux Enterprise Server  8+ SuSE SUSE Linux Enterprise Server  7Linux kernel 2.4.18 pre-8Linux kernel 2.4.18 pre-7Linux kernel 2.4.18 pre-6Linux kernel 2.4.18 pre-5Linux kernel 2.4.18 pre-4Linux kernel 2.4.18 pre-3Linux kernel 2.4.18 pre-2Linux kernel 2.4.18 pre-1Linux kernel 2.4.18  x86Linux kernel 2.4.18 + Astaro Security Linux 2.0 23+ Astaro Security Linux 2.0 16+ Debian Linux 3.0  sparc+ Debian Linux 3.0  s/390+ Debian Linux 3.0  ppc+ Debian Linux 3.0  mipsel+ Debian Linux 3.0  mips+ Debian Linux 3.0  m68k+ Debian Linux 3.0  ia-64+ Debian Linux 3.0  ia-32+ Debian Linux 3.0  hppa+ Debian Linux 3.0  arm+ Debian Linux 3.0  alpha+ Mandriva Linux Mandrake 8.2 + Mandriva Linux Mandrake 8.1 + Mandriva Linux Mandrake 8.0 + Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS  2.1 IA64+ RedHat Advanced Workstation for the Itanium Processor 2.1 IA64+ RedHat Advanced Workstation for the Itanium Processor 2.1 + RedHat Linux 8.0 + RedHat Linux 7.3 + S.u.S.E. Linux 8.1 + S.u.S.E. Linux 8.0 + S.u.S.E. Linux 7.3 + S.u.S.E. Linux 7.2 + S.u.S.E. Linux 7.1 + S.u.S.E. Linux Connectivity Server  + S.u.S.E. Linux Database Server  0+ S.u.S.E. Linux Firewall on CD  + S.u.S.E. Linux Office Server  + S.u.S.E. Linux Openexchange Server  + S.u.S.E. Linux Personal 8.2 + S.u.S.E. SuSE eMail Server 3.1 + S.u.S.E. SuSE eMail Server III  + SuSE SUSE Linux Enterprise Server  8+ SuSE SUSE Linux Enterprise Server  7+ Turbolinux Turbolinux Server 8.0 + Turbolinux Turbolinux Server 7.0 + Turbolinux Turbolinux Workstation 8.0 + Turbolinux Turbolinux Workstation 7.0 Linux kernel 2.4.17 Linux kernel 2.4.16 Linux kernel 2.4.15 Linux kernel 2.4.14 Linux kernel 2.4.13 + Caldera OpenLinux Server 3.1.1 + Caldera OpenLinux Workstation 3.1.1 Linux kernel 2.4.12 + Conectiva Linux 7.0 Linux kernel 2.4.11 Linux kernel 2.4.10 Linux kernel 2.4.9 + Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS  2.1 IA64+ Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS  2.1+ RedHat Enterprise Linux ES  2.1 IA64+ RedHat Enterprise Linux ES  2.1+ RedHat Enterprise Linux WS  2.1 IA64+ RedHat Enterprise Linux WS  2.1+ RedHat Linux 7.2  ia64+ RedHat Linux 7.2  i386+ RedHat Linux 7.2  alpha+ RedHat Linux 7.1  ia64+ RedHat Linux 7.1  i386+ RedHat Linux 7.1  alpha+ Sun Linux 5.0.5 + Sun Linux 5.0.3 + Sun Linux 5.0 Linux kernel 2.4.8 + Mandriva Linux Mandrake 8.2 + Mandriva Linux Mandrake 8.1 + Mandriva Linux Mandrake 8.0 Linux kernel 2.4.7 + RedHat Linux 7.2 + S.u.S.E. Linux 7.2 + S.u.S.E. Linux 7.1 Linux kernel 2.4.6 Linux kernel 2.4.5 + Slackware Linux 8.0 Linux kernel 2.4.4 + S.u.S.E. Linux 7.2 Linux kernel 2.4.3 + Mandriva Linux Mandrake 8.0  ppc+ Mandriva Linux Mandrake 8.0 Linux kernel 2.4.2 Linux kernel 2.4.1 Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test9Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test8Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test7Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test6Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test5Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test4Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test3Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test2Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test12Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test11Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test10Linux kernel 2.4 .0-test1Linux kernel 2.4 Debian Linux 3.1  sparcDebian Linux 3.1  s/390Debian Linux 3.1  ppcDebian Linux 3.1  mipselDebian Linux 3.1  mipsDebian Linux 3.1  m68kDebian Linux 3.1  ia-64Debian Linux 3.1  ia-32Debian Linux 3.1  hppaDebian Linux 3.1  armDebian Linux 3.1  amd64Debian Linux 3.1  alphaDebian Linux 3.1 Debian Linux 3.0  sparcDebian Linux 3.0  s/390Debian Linux 3.0  ppcDebian Linux 3.0  mipselDebian Linux 3.0  mipsDebian Linux 3.0  m68kDebian Linux 3.0  ia-64Debian Linux 3.0  ia-32Debian Linux 3.0  hppaDebian Linux 3.0  armDebian Linux 3.0  alphaDebian Linux 3.0'
```

I should to parse this and where I have + is a sub string .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where is this data being retrieved from? A DB or flat file?

Comment: @Hyperboreus he want to put all of that thing in a json file

Comment: I don't know syntex for storing this information in my json file.

Comment: I guess nobody will. E.g. why is `RedHat Enterprise Linux ES 2.1 IA64` a key, but at the same time only half of `Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS 2.1` is a key and the rest is part of an ungrammatical value. (Your JSON isn't even JSON).

Comment: @Talvalin this information is in a string .I want to read this and store it with this template in a json file.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the input string, since this will have to split up in order to create the required JSON.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I don't even know it's possible to have this json file.I think json is best for storing such this information.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see any logic between your input and your output: Some lines are split, others are not. Ubuntus disappear completely. Linux kernels 2.6.9 to 2.6.8 rc1 go with RHEL AS 2.1, but 2.6.8 doesn't. In which way is your output related to your input?

Comment: this string is vulnerable Operating Systems for a vulnerability.like Red "RedHat Enterprise Linux WS  2.1 IA64" and "Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc1".but "Linux kernel 2.6.8 rc1" is vulnerable in "Ubuntu Linux 4.1 ppc" and "Ubuntu Ubuntu Linux 4.1 ia64" versions.I think It's the best way to use json that store it.

Comment: Are you retrieving this information from a website (eg: http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/20959)? If so, why not use Beautiful Soup to parse the webpage and output the data?

Comment: @Talvalin yes It's securityfocus.com .I read vulnerable in a string.how can store this part in a right way?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the problem you are trying to solve and also through a sample SecurityFocus Bid article ( in this case - securityfocus.com/bid/20959). The idea here is to extract text from  the web page using a scraper like **BeautifulSoup**. This text can then be parsed to convert the information into a JSON object that can then be dumped to a file.
The information from the TexInfo file on SecurityFocus contains all the vulnerable operating systems list within a single  tag. Related kernels for a flavor of the operating system( for e.g. SuSE Linux 8.0) appear below it and are preceded with a **+** sign (for e.g. + Linux Kernel 2.4.5). The **+** sign is actually not a simple **+** sign but something like **\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t+**. This makes it necessary to process the strings before converting them to JSON. The below code snippet does this task for the url [securityfocus.com/bid/20959](http://securityfocus.com/bid/20959).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import json

response = urllib2.urlopen(r'http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/20959')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div_element = soup.find(id="vulnerability")
tr_element = div_element.find_all(valign="top")

td_elements =  tr_element[1].find_all("td")

os_names_list = []
for os_name in td_elements[1].stripped_strings:
    os_names_list.append(os_name)

related_kernel_indices = []
[related_kernel_indices.append(i) for i in range(0,len(os_names_list)) if os_names_list[i].startswith('+')]
for i in range(0,len(related_kernel_indices)):
    os_names_list[related_kernel_indices[i]] = os_names_list[related_kernel_indices[i] - i - 1] + '-' + " ".join(os_names_list[related_kernel_indices[i]].split()[1:])


#loop through the modified list and create a dictionary of OS names along with the correspoding kernel relations
vulnerability_os_mapping = {}

for os_name_entry in os_names_list:
    related_kernels = []
    os_name_components = os_name_entry.split('-')
    if not vulnerability_os_mapping.has_key(os_name_components[0]):
        vulnerability_os_mapping[os_name_components[0]] = related_kernels
    elif len(os_name_components) > 1:
        vulnerability_os_mapping[os_name_components[0]].append(os_name_components[1])

#create a file with a template name - vulnerability_list_<bid_id>.json
vulnerability_list_file = open('vulnerability_list_20959.json','w')
json.dump(vulnerability_os_mapping, vulnerability_list_file)
```

I hope this gives you an idea on how to go about performing such as task.